# Post request doesn't reach Node from Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm triggering this function called upload() by clicking on submit button on the frontend.

in my app.html:

```
<div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:10px;" (click)="upload()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

in my app.ts:

```
upload() {

    this.files = {
      pdf_one: './server/test-pdfs/pdf-sample.pdf',
      pdf_two:  './server/test-pdfs/pdf-sample.pdf',
    };

    this.filesToUpload = [];

    this.filesToUpload.push(this.files.pdf_one);
    this.filesToUpload.push(this.files.pdf_two);

    this.getMergedPDF(this.filesToUpload);
}

getMergedPDF(filesToUpload): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8081/merge-pdf', JSON.stringify(filesToUpload));
 }
```

I've set breakpoints and the function above is being called just fine. It's just when it gets to the node.js side, nothing is triggered.

Here's how I set the api endpoint on nodejs side: 
    server.js

```
app.post('/merge-pdf', (req, res) => {
    this.fileList  = req;

    PDFMerge(this.fileList, {output: `${__dirname}/test-pdfs/merged-pdf.pdf`});
    res.send(200);
});

const server = app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port %s...', server.address().port);
});
```

I was wondering what I could be doing wrong above that the api endpoint is not triggered?

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
getMergedPDF(filesToUpload): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8081/merge-pdf', JSON.stringify(filesToUpload))
    .subscribe(data  => this.mergedUrl = data);
  }
```

But this error happens:

```
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.'
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually subscribing to the `Observable` returned by `getMergedPDF()`, which means the POST request will never be executed.

Comment: remove that  Observable<string> return type from EDIT becuase you're returning subscription instead

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik thank you so much. That was the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to it. Observables are lazy, and won't actually perform the POST call unless you subscribe to it.

```
this.http.post(...).subscribe(...)
```

You can make sure Node is not in fault by checking your browser's Network tab and see that no HTTP call is made in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I am trying this: getMergedPDF(filesToUpload): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8081/merge-pdf', JSON.stringify(filesToUpload))
    .subscribe(this.mergedUrl => data);
  }  But then I get this error:  'Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) => void'.'

Comment: No, `.subscribe(data => this.mergedUrl = data)`, but this is another problem. Is the HTTP call firing now? If yes, this question is solved

Comment: can you check my edit above? I still get an error for using .subscribe

Comment: I get: 'Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.'

Comment: Then I don't know. I always use `.post(...).subscribe( data => ...... )` and it works in all my projects.

Comment: Ok np... I think you're on the right track about the subscribe though. I'll look through the documentation to make sure it's setup properly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, Wilheim above in the comments of the post mentioned to remove: Observable<string> because I'm returning subscription and that fixed it. Thanks a lot to both of you!  I'll mark this as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I thought about that but I thought I was wrong so I didn't say it :) Glad we fixed it